# Electron-fetch returns json as [object object] but network console shows a proper json object being returned

Tags: javascript, json, electron, fetch

I am working on a project using electron and reactjs. I am therefore using electron-fetch to fetch data from an API using JSON to send and return JSON response.

In the network console I can see I get the expected result (I also use test client (Insomnia) and confirm I get a JSON response which is as follows:

```
{
  "result": 0,
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "MonitorId": 2,
      "LogName": "Test",
      "LogPath": "/root/test"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, in the electron app, in the network tab response I can see the JSON object as above but I get the following error shown in the console

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at index.es.js:234

When I print out the response.body I see [object object] instead of the actual JSON.

Below is my fetch request

```
try
{
    fetch(url, {
         method: 'post',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'authorisation_token': authorisation
         },
         mode: 'cors',
         body: JSON.stringify(postArray)
    }).then(function (response) {
         if (response.status !== 200)
         {
             console.log("Something went wrong. Status Code: " + response.status);
             reject(response);
             return;
         }

         console.log(response);

         response.json().then(function (data) {
             resolve(data);
         }).catch(function (err) {
             console.error("Caught Error: " + err);
             reject(err);
         });
    });
}
catch (err)
{
   console.error(err);
}
```

I've recently used normal fetch in the same way and not had a problem, so not sure if this is something specific to electron-fetch or whether I'm missing something here.

Comment: Why are there `resolve()` and `reject()` calls? `fetch()` returns a `Promise`, hence there's no need for an additional `Promise` around it,

Comment: @Andreas I'm calling the fetch within my own helper method, which returns a promise, so when my method completes where its gets called can get the promise call back

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the error either at first glance - does the inbuilt electron `net` API return the json correctly? If yes, it may be worth to have a closer look at the library?

Comment: Not sure I've never used that. Only just started using electron/react. From taking a quick look I guess I need to run that from start.js (where the BrowserWindow is created)?

Comment: You need to run it somewhere in the main process (I guessed that you want to use it in the main process - or you would have used the browser windows fetch() ). You should be able to run this api even without creating a BrowserWindow (just using electron to run your script instead of node). For me it helped a lot to think of electron as an extended node.js runtime.

Comment: Can I post readable code in chat? Then I could put together an example for the net API this weekend. If you want :)

Comment: Although its an electron app, I am not doing the API request from Electron, I'm trying to do it from the react component in the `componentDidMount` method. I was initially trying to use the normal fetch but I got a constructor error and I found a post on here somewhere saying I should use electron-fetch. Maybe this is the correct thing to do either as I'm doing it from React?

Comment: ahh, I see. Do you load the site from the react devserver (in case you used create-react-app) in the electron window or do you build it first and then load it in the window (I want to try to reproduce this).

Comment: I load the site from the react devserver I believe, I did use the create-react-app. I followed the guide from https://flaviocopes.com/react-electron/.

Comment: ok, I see now the unexpected behaviour of the original fetch -  fetch... does not do what you would think it does. If you log the response.text() you will see that it has nothing to do with the response of your server. At least on my machine it returns my own files o.O looking further into this...

Comment: I think I sussed it, I had a look at a project that uses Electron and React (Insomnia.Rest) and found when they do a request they don't seem to use electron-fetch just normal fetch but they do `window.fetch()` and when I tried that it seems to work as expected. I'm doing a bit more testing as literally just figured that out so making sure there's no other surprises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I had a look at a project that uses Electron and React (Insomnia.Rest) and found when they do a request they don't seem to use electron-fetch just normal fetch but they do `window.fetch()` and when I tried that it seems to work as expected